# transpose rows to columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and need help for transposing rows to columns in mysql database
I have gone through some examples of transpose but slightly confused in using right syntax
and some existing answers add additional requirements which make it slighly different

my exiting table is and rows are more than below shared fews rows for explanation

```
+----------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+--------+
| Item     |     YEAR  |  Sales |   Profit |  TSV      |   REC  |
+----------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+--------+
| machine  |      2011 |      10|     10   |   20      |     10 |
| machine  |      2010 |      8 |     15   |    6      |      2 |
| machine  |      2013 |      15|     5    |   11      |      5 |
| machine  |      2009 |      3 |     8    |    9      |     13 |
| machine  |      2012 |      6 |     12   |   18      |     16 |
| decors   |      2010 |      11|     10   |   13      |     22 |
| decors   |      2011 |      9 |     9    |   16      |     12 |
| decors   |      2012 |      3 |     7    |   11      |      9 |
| decors   |      2013 |      13|     23   |    9      |     10 |
| decors   |      2009 |      4 |     9    |   10      |      8 |
| sp parts |      2009 |      22|     25   |   17      |     22 |
| sp parts |      2010 |      21|     22   |   11      |     14 |
| sp parts |      2011 |      28|     30   |   29      |     23 |
| sp parts |      2012 |      23|     28   |   12      |      8 |
| sp parts |      2013 |      21|     24   |   24      |     32 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

and expected table after transpose is

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Item         machine machine machine machine machine decors  decors  decors  decors decors sp parts sp parts sp parts sp parts sp parts |
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | YEAR     2011    2010    2013    2009    2012    2010    2011    2012    2013        2009    2009    2010    2011    2012    2013       |
 | Sales    10  8   15  3   6   11  9   3   13  4   22  21  28  23  21         |
 | Profit   10  15  5   8   12  10  9   7   23  9   25  22  30  28  24         |
 | TSV          20  6   11  9   18  13  16  11  9   10  17  11  29  12  24         |
 | REC      10  2   5   13  16  22  12  9   10  8   22  14  23  8   32         |
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

can someone help with this question

Comment: For what it's worth, the jargon for what you're trying to do is *pivoting.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: As far as I know MySql doesn't have true PIVOT table support but there's information on the web on how to hack it..